# Was Isabel Dodson Mammon's original choice?

Tags: dc, constantine-2005

In the movie *Constantine*, Isabel Dodson commits suicide, after which her twin, Angela, seeks Constantine's assistance. Angela ends up being key in Mammon's plan to claim the earth.

Both Isabel and Angela had the same abilities in their youth as John Constantine has. While Isabel embraced hers, driving her insane, Angela rejected them, which led to loss of her ability (which was revived by Constantine).

Considering this, was Isabel Mammon's original choice, only switching to Angela when Isabel committed suicide?

Is there anything in the original comic, the script, deleted scenes or in other materials that explains this?

Comment: I never got that impression. It's been a long time since I listened to the commentary, but I don't recall them mentioning anything like that. It's also never really clear (that I can recall) why Mammon wanted/needed someone with the sight, in particular.

Comment: To nitpick, Isabel wasn't actually insane - it's just that everyone THOUGHT she was because of what she described seeing & talked about. Angels? Demons? Pfft - obviously this girl is insane.

Comment: @Omegacron - The implication was that she wasn't insane *to begin with* but that after multiple incarcerations, drug-therapy and ECT she had become unhinged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Constantine-John-Shirley/dp/0743497554) explicitly states that Isabel was indeed Mammon's first choice:

> And she understood then. Mammon had found another oracle. "Twins," she said breathlessly.
>   She and Isabel had the same powers. In her, they'd been dormant, till lately. But the power was there. **Mammon had lost Isabel - she'd sacrificed herself so that they couldn't use her to open the way for Mammon. But they had someone else. Someone quite handy.**
>
> Mammon could use Angela to complete the opening of the doorway; to populate Earth with
>   the denizens of Hell; to make the unsuspecting world of men a literal Hell on Earth.
>   Probably, Constantine mused, the flying demons hadn't been trying to kill Angela. Him?
>   Yeah. But they'd have just captured Angela.

Notably, Isabel herself considers herself chosen (marked) by evil forces

> She [Isabel] rubs her wrist-the mark there, the strange circular
>   symbol that burns there... and she knows in her heart what it means.
>   It means she's been chosen. And she can't let that happen..

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes Isabel was Mammon's first choice.

Mammon wanted to use Isabel as a gateway to the mortal plane. Isabel knows this and commits suicide to stop him. Presumably, because Isabel had accepted her gifts from a young age, she was more susceptible to whatever Mammon had planned.

Because she committed suicide, she was condemned to Hell, but actually her suicide was much closer to self-sacrifice, as she killed herself to stop Mammon, so she really should have got directly into Heaven.

I'm trying to find a reference for this now but I think it's implied in the movie. Mammon needed a powerful psychic and he chose Isabel. Only switching to Angie after Isabel's death.